# Burninate [inversion] and [invert]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Looking at the highest-voted [inversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inversion) questions (72 total), I see:

- [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) inversion
- [inversion-of-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inversion-of-control)
- [regex-negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-negation)
- [mathematical inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/inverse/info)
- inversion of [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors)
- [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation)
- something weird in SQL, probably [depth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search)

For [invert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invert) (115 total), we get:

- inversion of [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors)
- reversing text in [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)
- reverse [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map)s
- something over my head involving [function-composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-composition) in Haskell
- [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation) again
- digit-wise reversal of integers
- something with [jquery-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) sliders

If there's anything in common other than that most of them can (if you squint) be seen as special cases of [mathematical inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/inverse/info), I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Eh, I started doing this, and stopped after about 20 tag removals.  In retrospect, matrix inversion is a thing, and removing the [inversion] tag from those questions makes them harder to search.  In general, I think y'all are way too picky about these kinds of tags, especially given the friction the tag management tools have.

Comment: I'd have no quarrel with a matrix-inversion tag.

Comment: Sure, but I'm not going to go to the trouble of making one, since searching on [matrix][inversion] already works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So burninating is a positive action and adding matrix-inversion is a positive action. So burninating is a positive action.